# How to play video with vitamio 5.0.2 in background in android?

Tags: android, vitamio

How can I play a video/audio in background with `vitamio` library in Android

```
List Videos -> Click on a Video -> Video starts playing -> press the Home button -> video/audio stopps.
```

Comment: Is Vitamio any kind of SDK?

Comment: @Palak - i'm not sure, just tried it. You can find more info here: https://www.vitamio.org/en/ Anyway i solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use service for solution?

Comment: No, i don't. I'm still using vitamio, just comment realease(true) method in surfaceDestroyed() and call release(true) in onDetach() in my fragment.

Comment: How much exp you have?

Comment: @Palak - more 2 years :)

Comment: If you have the solution for this. Please answer your question to help others who get same problem.

Comment: @Vũ Tuấn Anh: pls have a look the 4th comment that's my solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i have solved my task by my way.
I'm still using vitamio, just comment realease(true) method in surfaceDestroyed() and call release(true) in onDetach() in my fragment. Hope this can help someone has the same problem.